# Any reason as to why passing an object using jsp:include tag into another jsp isn't working in this scenario?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, jstl

I have an index.jsp that contains an object named event that I wish to access in another jsp named event.jsp. However, using a jsp:include tag like some have suggested doesn't seem to be working?

Can anyone notice anything missing that is required to display this?

**index.jsp**

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${events}" var="event" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="event" value="${event}" scope="request"/>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="event.jsp">"${event.eventID}"</a></td>
            <td>"${event.title}"</td>   
            <td>"${event.venue}"</td>   
            <td>"${event.dateTime}"</td>    
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

**event.jsp**

```
<h1><c:out value="${requestScope.event.eventID}"/></h1>
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

As per the suggestion below this works in terms of passing the data, but replicates the page for every event in the events list. Is there anywhere i can import the event page outside of the loop so that it isn't repeated?

**index.jsp**

```
 <table>
        <c:forEach items="${events}" var="event" varStatus="status">
        <c:set var="event" value="${event}" scope="request"/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <jsp:include page="event.jsp">
                       <jsp:param name="myVar" value="${event}"/>
                 </jsp:include>
                </td>
                <td>"${event.title}"</td>   
                <td>"${event.venue}"</td>   
                <td>"${event.dateTime}"</td>    
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

**event.jsp**

```
<c:out value="${param.myVar}"/>
```

Comment: Please check below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below way.Might be help you.
index.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${events}" var="event">
            ${event.name}-${event.city}
    </c:forEach>

<c:import url="two.jsp" />
```

two.jsp

```
    <c:forEach items="${events}" var="event">

            ${event.name}-${event.city}
    </c:forEach>
```

Here i can iterate events list to included jsp also.

Comment: This allows me to pass data through, so thanks for that one. One thing however is that due to the jsp:include being inside the for each loop a new page is being created inside the index.jsp for every event. Is it possible to move this elsewhere so that this doesnt happen. Thanks